# Set default value for NULL in datatable

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, .net-datatable

I have the following codes, which I created as extension for datatable in my project.
It actually worked. Just wonder if there is any optimization can be made through. Thanks. =)

```
<Extension()>
Public Function HasNull(ByVal dataTable As DataTable) As Boolean
    For Each column As DataColumn In dataTable.Columns
        If dataTable.Rows.OfType(Of DataRow)().Any(Function(r) r.IsNull(column)) Then
            Return True
        End If
    Next
    Return False
End Function

<Extension()>
Public Function SetDefaultForNull(ByVal dataTable As DataTable) As DataTable
    For Each row As DataRow In dataTable.Rows
        For Each col As DataColumn In dataTable.Columns
            Dim value As Object = row(col)
            If IsDBNull(value) Then
                Dim dataType As String = col.DataType.ToString

                Select Case dataType
                    Case "System.DateTime"
                        value = New DateTime
                    Case "System.Decimal", "System.Int16", "System.Int32", "System.Int64"
                        value = 0
                    Case "System.String"
                        value = String.Empty
                    Case "System.Boolean"
                        value = False
                    Case Else
                        value = 0
                End Select
                row(col) = value
            End If
        Next
    Next
    Return dataTable
End Function
```

Comment: I'm rolling back the last edit as it invalidates my answer. Please see this meta post. [For an iterative review, is it ok to edit my question to include updated code?](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1763/for-an-iterative-review-is-it-okay-to-edit-my-own-question-to-include-revised-c).

Comment: Welcome to CR @chinz. We're not trying to be mean, we're glad you're here. We just have some rules. Feel free to drop by [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor) if you have any questions about how the site works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit to [@Tim Schmelter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24956404):

> According to the first method: I would handle the case that the input
>   table is Nothing, either throw an ArgumentNullException or return
>   True/False.
>
> Also another minor improvement: i would loop the rows instead of the
>   columns. Consider that all columns are non-null except the last. You
>   would loop all rows for all column before you detect a null. If you
>   loop the rows you'd determined that already in the first row(if the
>   last column is full of nulls).
>
> So something like this:
>
> ```
> <Extension()>
> Public Function HasNull(dataTable As DataTable) As Boolean
>     If dataTable Is Nothing Then
>         Throw New ArgumentNullException("dataTable must be initialized", "dataTable")
>     End If
>     Dim allColumns = dataTable.Columns.Cast(Of DataColumn).ToList() ' materialize
>     Dim hasNullField As Boolean = dataTable.AsEnumerable().
>         Any(Function(row) allColumns.Any(Function(c) row.IsNull(c)))
>     Return hasNullField
> End Function
> ```
>
> The second method could use this extension instead to get the default
>   value of all types:
>
> ```
> <Extension()>
> Public Function GetDefaultValue(t As Type) As Object
>     If t.IsValueType Then
>         Return Activator.CreateInstance(t)
>     Else
>         Return Nothing
>     End If
> End Function
> ```
>
> The second method itself could then be implemented in this way(make it
>   a Sub):
>
> ```
> <Extension()>
> Public Sub SetDefaultForNull(dataTable As DataTable)
>     For Each row As DataRow In dataTable.Rows
>         For Each col As DataColumn In dataTable.Columns
>             If row.IsNull(col) Then
>                 row.SetField(col, col.DataType.GetDefaultValue())
>             End If
>         Next
>     Next
> End Sub
> ```
>
> Tested with this sample data:
>
> ```
> Dim table As New DataTable
> table.Columns.Add("ID", GetType(Int32))
> table.Columns.Add("Name", GetType(String))
> table.Columns.Add("Date", GetType(DateTime))
> table.Rows.Add(1, "test", DateTime.Now)
> table.Rows.Add(DBNull.Value, Nothing, Nothing)
> table.Rows.Add(Nothing, DBNull.Value, DBNull.Value)
> If table.HasNull() Then
>     table.SetDefaultForNull()
> End If
> ```
>
> Result:
>
> > ```
> > 1       test    25.07.2014 15:05:29
> > 0               01.01.0001 00:00:00
> > 0               01.01.0001 00:00:00
> > ```

Answer (score 4):

A couple of small points.

- Single letter identifiers and variable names are the devil incarnate. Replace `r` with something meaningful.
- There's not much point in using a variable for `col.DataType.ToString`. You only use the variable `dataType` once, so it would be perfectly acceptable to get rid of a line of a code and do this instead.

  ```
  Select Case col.DataType.ToString
      Case "System.DateTime"
          value = New DateTime
  ```
- I also don't see much benefit to the `value` variable. You could just set `row(col) =` to whatever you would set `value` to.
- There's no reason to explicitly check for `Case "System.Decimal", "System.Int16", "System.Int32", "System.Int64"`. It's taken care of in the `Else` case.

  ```
  Select Case col.DataType.ToString
      Case "System.DateTime"
          row(col) = New DateTime
      Case "System.String"
          row(col) = String.Empty
      Case "System.Boolean"
          row(col) = False
      Case Else
          row(col) = 0
  End Select
  ```

Comment: `Single letter identifiers and variable names are the devil incarnate` I saw someone invoke the devil by using a script with single letter only, it was horrible!